# Go fmt.Scanln that doesn't echo back characters typed by user. For password

Tags: go

How do I capture user input from the command line without echoing back the characters that the user types. I want to use this to capture a password. Like [getpass.getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) in Python.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var password string
    fmt.Scanln(&password)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no helper function in the standard library for this.

You have to create your own, or use an existing one like [**gopass**](https://github.com/howeyc/gopass) (supports windows, unix, bsd).

**Using gopass:** (example taken from their website)

```
import "fmt"
import "github.com/howeyc/gopass"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Password: ")
    pass := gopass.GetPasswd() // Silent, for *'s use gopass.GetPasswdMasked()
    // Do something with pass
}
```

Comment: @Neil I edited my answer, the "new" linked gopass is also cross platform.